# Change image icon of currently selected row item in listview android

Tags: android, listview, selecteditem

In my `ListView`, I have `TextView` and `Imageview` in one row. `Listview` row data are coming from local database. Now when user touches any row for selection, I want to change that row item image. Now again when user close this app and open again, I want to set new image to `imageview` of that row which was selected last time.

Also 2nd activity is called when user select any row of `listview`. and when user press back button from that new activity, the selected row's `imageview` is not changed, displaying original image only. I have used below code, but it is not working perfectly.

here is activity's onstart method:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  int pos = prefs.getInt(PrefernceData.PREF_CURR_SELECTED_ID, -1);
  for(int  i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    if(Integer.parseInt(text[i][0]) == pos){
      dotPosition = i;
    }
}
```

listview itemclick method:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {

dotPosition = position;
clearSelection();

lastSelectedView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.doticon);
ImageView v = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.doticon);
v.setImageResource(R.drawable.dothighlight);
prefs.edit().putInt(PrefernceData.PREF_CURR_SELECTED_ID, Integer.parseInt(text[position][0]).commit();
Intent i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Here is clearselection method:

```
public void clearSelection() {
  if(lastSelectedView != null) {
    Log.i("myLog","clear selection:lastselected icon::");
    lastSelectedView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
  }
}
```

and here is adapter's getview method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  ViewHolder holder;
  LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(myActivity.this);

  if(convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.site_listview_items, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.siteText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.homesitelisttext);
    holder.dotIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.doticon);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
  } else {
    holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
  }

  holder.siteText.setText(text[position][1]);
  Log.i("myLog","position::"+position+"dotPosition:"+dotPosition);

  if(position == dotPosition) {
    holder.dotIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.dothighlight);
    lastSelectedView = holder.dotIcon;
  } else {
    holder.dotIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
  }

  return convertView;
}
```